# mpi4py: isend behaves strangely if communicating processes run on different machines

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I'm testing non-blocking communication supported by mpi4py and have encountered unexpected (at least for me) behavior of `isend`:  for some reason a message sent with `isend` doesn't get delivered until the sending process is finished or `wait` method of request instance returned by `isend` is called, which nullifies the usefulness of `isend`.

**This behavior is observed only if the processes run on different machines.**

The code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import socket
from time import sleep,time


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
node=socket.gethostname()


print 'rank {} on {}'.format(rank,node)
if rank == 1:
    message=1
    req_send=comm.isend(message, dest=0, tag=11)
    #req_send.wait() #no issue if uncommented
    sleep(10)
    print 'sending process finished'

elif rank == 0:
    t=time()
    data=comm.recv(source=1, tag=11)
    print 'message recieved: {}, waiting time: {}'.format( data,time()-t)
```

**Results/outputs:**

**1**.Different machines, `#req_send.wait()` line commented out (**faulty setting**; message is received only after sending process is finished, which adds 10 seconds to waiting time):

```
rank 0 on node1
rank 1 on node2
sending process finished
message recieved: 1, waiting time: 10.0342979431
```

**2**.Different machines, `req_send.wait()` line uncommented:

```
rank 0 on node1
rank 1 on node2
message recieved: 1, waiting time: 0.000602006912231
sending process finished
```

**3**.Same machine, with or without `req_send.wait()` line :

```
rank 1 on node1
rank 0 on node1
message recieved: 1, waiting time: 2.09808349609e-05
sending process finished
```

I tried several mpi4py builds for ancaconda2 and behaviour is similar. But using *anaconda mpi4py* and **faulty setting** results in **additional error** appearing in the output:

```
rank 0 on node1
rank 1 on node2
sending process finished
message recieved: 1, waiting time: 10.0120418072
Assertion failed in file ch3u_handle_connection.c at line 332: vc->state == MPIDI_VC_STATE_LOCAL_CLOSE || vc->state == MPIDI_VC_STATE_CLOSE_ACKED
internal ABORT - process 1
```

What might cause this problem? How can it be solved/approached?

Comment: You call it an "additional warning" but the error message says "internal ABORT" which doesn't sound like a warning, it sounds like a crash.

Comment: @John Zwinck, thanks for the comment, yes, probably it's more appropriate to call it an error. I've edited the text.

Comment: The MPI standard does **not** guarantee `MPI_Isend()` starts sending the message. Unless your MPI library had a progress thread (most libs do not implement one on most interconnects) nothing will happen unless a/some MPI subroutines are invoked by the sender.